# Should I upload "node_modules"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, node-modules

I am making a web page, `node_modules` file is around 150 megabytes, should I upload it or not? Is there any way to make it smaller? I am using "filezilla" and it would take too long to upload it.

Comment: No you should not .The size of node_module will be pretty big rather uploading `package.json` file will be enough

Comment: if case of git, `node_modules` are kept under `gitignore`, and dependencies track is done using `package.json` file

Comment: you should have a `package.json` with the list of dependencies and run `npm install` on the server -- this will generate the `node_modules` folder on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node modules is where all the external libraries you use for your application are kept. The list of those libraries should be mentioned in `package.json` file.

You should, typically, not upload node modules folder manually. They are the external libraries and are easily available to install separately. So, when moving files through filezilla, move everything but node modules. Then, in your server, simple run `npm i` before running the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `package.json` file and used `npm module -s <package_name>` (with -s or --save) then everything was fine.

If you don't have it no worries.Transfer the files into your online services like AWS,Something like that.

Then give the commands.

```
// For install npm

  npm i
    (or) 
  npm install

// To start your server

  npm start
```

Whatever you put in your `package.json` file Start Object the file will be triggered.

No need to copy the node_modules folder at all.